# Accessing specific array element in an Angular2 Template

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have an array that I can loop through using `ng-for` syntax. However, ultimately I want to access just a single element of that array. I cannot figure out how to do that.

In my component script I have

```
  export class TableComponent {

    elements: IElement[];

}
```

In my template, I am able to loop through the elements via

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor='let element of elements'>{{element.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

However, trying to access an item in the element array by secifically referencing an item utilizing

```
  x {{elements[0].name}}x
```

does not seem to work.

The formatting in the template is pretty explicit, so I want to be able to access each element of the array explicitly in the template.

I am not understanding something basic....

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**2020 Edit :**

```
{{elements?.[0].name}}
```

is the new way for the null check

**Original answer :**
{{elements[0].name}}

should just work. If you load `elements` async (from a server or similar) then Angular fails when it tries to update the binding before the response from the server arrived (which is usually the case). You should get an error message in the browser console though.

Try instead

```
{{elements && elements[0].name}}
```

Comment: This was exactly the issue. Async call and the data was not initialized on load. This is a bit different behavior than Angular 1.x.

Thanks!

Comment: @RamiAlloush what Dart/Flutter version?

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer, I thought we were talking about Angular :D. I'm running Angular v9. I just want to do `elements?.[0]` but I can't. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Work around, use ngIf check the length. **elements?** means if elements is null,  don't read the **length** property.

```
<div *ngIf="elements?.length">
    {{elements[0].name}}
</div>
```