# JSON with name Zero

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm making a http request to a JSON server, and putting the value inside a variable, when a I make a `console.log()` it shows me all information from the json, but when I try to use the interpolation to bring the information to the template, it throws me this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'numero' of undefined
```

A notted that the json comes with zero on his name, how can I Solve that?

My service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { API } from '../../../app.api';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TarefadetalheService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  recuperaDetalhes(): any{
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:4000/tarefadetalhe")

 }
}
```

Here's my page that calls the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';
import { TarefadetalheService } from './tarefadetalhe.service';
import { Tarefa } from '../../models/tarefa.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tarefas-detalhe',
  templateUrl: './tarefas-detalhe.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tarefas-detalhe.page.scss'],
})
export class TarefasDetalhePage implements OnInit {
 idTarefa = null
 tarefa: any
  constructor(private navParams: NavParams, private getTarefaDetalhe: TarefadetalheService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.idTarefa = this.navParams.get('id_tarefa');
    this.getTarefaDetalhe.recuperaDetalhes().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.tarefa = data[0] //now it works 
    })
  }
}
```

Heres my template:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>{{tarefa.numero}}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
ID da tarefa é: {{idTarefa}}
</ion-content>
```

As you can see now I can show the data as I wanted, but it keeps me throwing error, I just tried to run `ionic serve` again and no effect
[image]

I've tried to make {{tarefa[0].numero}} but this way he does not even shows me the data in the template.

Comment: It's an array, `tarefa[0].numero` should work just fine

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544503/accessing-specific-array-element-in-an-angular2-template

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing specific array element in an Angular2 Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544503/accessing-specific-array-element-in-an-angular2-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that with capturing the index of json like below-

```
this.tarefa = data[0] 
console.log(this.tarefa)//Here I can show the data
```

and then `{{tarefa.numero}}` should work for you.

Comment: Now the data is rendering, but keep throwing me error, as you can see... I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

As others have said this.tarefa is an array, the object with all the data you want is in the first element of the array.

Either access it by

```
this.tarefa[0].numero
```

or when you retrieve the data and store it in the tarefa variable just store the 1st (and only) element of the array.

```
this.tarefa = data[0]
```

Comment: The second suggestion worked for me, and the template is ok now, but the console keeps throwing me error and I don't know why :/

Comment: you must be calling tarefa.numero before the get request to the API is actually completed.

Comment: So, I have to do Async and await?? I know what it do, but I dont know how to implement, could ou help me?

Comment: Sorry I dont really know Angular all that well. You dont need to use async await, but you need to tell Angular NOT to load up the template until the data is actually fetched.

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900769/angular-wait-until-i-receive-data-before-loading-template

Comment: @TiagoSilveira hahaha thats awesome!